# Import a Markdown inside a Markdown / README.md

Tags: github, import, markdown, readme

I have a folder structure that looks like this on GitHub:

```
Project
 |
 +-- Readme.md
 |    
 +-- Images
 |  |  
 |  \-- example.png
 |  \-- general.png
 +-- markdown
 |  \-- table.md
```

I can successfully import, and show, images with the command

```
![](Images/example.png "Example")
```

But if I try the same thing with the markdown:

```
![](markdown/table.md "A markdown table?")
```

It does not appear.

The actual README.md along with folder structure can be seen [here](https://github.com/SpangeJ/Code/blob/master/MATLAB/diceRoll/README.md?plain=1)
And *table.md* is shown [here](https://github.com/SpangeJ/Code/blob/master/MATLAB/diceRoll/markdown/table.md)

Any clues on why it does not work?